# Android & Google maps v2 : is it possible to show a map from city name?

Tags: android, google-maps

Before integrating Google Maps v2 in my app, i would to know if it is possible to show a city on a map without having latitude and longitude properties ?

I would like that the user provide a city name, and automatically the city is shown on the map. (Like Google Maps website in fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using the [Geocoder class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).

The method `public List<Address> getFromLocationName (String locationName, int maxResults)` seems to do what you want.